# RAID server went dark

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, raid, raid-5

So I have a Gigabyte 277x MB with a Intel i5 that has been running 2 software raid arrays on Ubuntu for 3 years without issue. Last night I turned off server to move it and clean it and then turned it back on and wont boot. Go into Bios and only 3 of my 9 drives are recognized (Drives are WD 8tb NAS red drives, all but 1). I start moving Sata cables around and testing via my OS SSD which was recognized on all cables and ports.

I bought an external enclosure and tested on server via USB installation and it recognizes the drives as (SDC, SDD, SDE) but read/write output error. There was a ubuntu update I did before reset but that shouldnt affect if the bios see's it or not.

lshw - https://pastebin.com/Mq5tFuDy
lsblk - https://pastebin.com/sJcsrDMZ
blkid - https://pastebin.com/31gTgrsD
FSTAB - https://pastebin.com/QEXkU0at
lsscsi - https://pastebin.com/VNqzzPqi

Edit, here is log from smartctl on drive in enclosure - https://pastebin.com/B8p4knUs

Here is result from dmde - https://ibb.co/N3rZWwT

Comment: If it's thoughts you want, my first thought is, this happens quite a ,lot after cleaning and so most common issue it something isn't properly connected/attached. Assuming a drive issue, each drive has to be diagnosed separately, at least SMART needs to be examined.

Comment: @ShaneGreenfield please do not put information into comments ... this site is not a forum ... edit your question instead ... also add text, not links to text ... also, get rid of the `any thoughts?` question, it's not a question about a computer problem

Comment: What do you get from smartctl with the `-d sat` parameter? (SAT should generally work unless the USB enclosure is ancient.)

Comment: @u1686_grawity Here is pastebin, thank you for the correct parameter.

https://pastebin.com/B8p4knUs

Comment: Somehow you'll need to be diagnosing these drives, so if this particular USB enclosure/adapter is the issue (which I do not believe) get another one or attach the drive to a native port. USB adapters are in fact the worst when dealing with any serious drive issues. To me it sounds as if at least some of the drives have issues.

Comment: I posted info above about diagnostics via the USB enclosure